# History Search (Ctrl+r) sometimes only allows me to search for 2 characters

Tags: bash, command-history

History Search (Ctrl+r) sometimes only allows me to search for 2 characters

When this happens i need to close the tab and create a new one....I wish i knew what i was doing wrong to cause this to happen so i don't have to close and reopen tabs.  Can anyone tell me?

1. Ctrl+r
2. Enter sudo
3. But it stops at the first 2 characters:

(reverse-i-search)`su': sudo su username

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, except it doesn't work even after closing and reopening tabs :(

Comment: check my accepted answer...that will explain

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue as the commenter on the accepted answer - the command exists in history, but the search stops. I found a few other posts about the same thing but I haven't found the cause or fix yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That means that it was unable to find any command entries beyond those 2 characters. For example, if you type `cd`, it will return the latest cd command:

> ```
> (reverse-i-search)`cd': cd $HOME
> ```

if you type `cdr` and it doesn't find any matching commands, it will ignore and omit the last character(s) and display what it **was** able to find

> ```
> (reverse-i-search)`cd': cd $HOME
> ```

Comment: You didn't answer the actual query. I have faced same issues even if history was available.

Comment: @bit_cracker007  if that is the case...than what you are searching for may not actually be in your history...enter history to see if what you are searching for is actually there.

Comment: As said, it's there in ```history```.

Comment: @bit_cracker007 - can you show me a screenshot of the problem?